# C++ overloaded operator []

Tags: c++, class, operator-overloading, runtime-error, subscript-operator

I have made a application where you type the amount of books you want to enter and using overloaded operator ([]) but every time I give a pointer to store an array, it gives me an errors such as

> 2 IntelliSense: expression must have integral or unscoped enum
>   type      Line:11 Column:24   Library Books

and

> Error 1   error C2440: 'initializing' : cannot convert from
>   'std::string' to 'unsigned int'       Line:11 Column:1    Library Books

but anyway here is my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

class Books{
private:
    string* storage;
    string book;
public:
    Books(){
        storage = new string[book];
    }
    void savebooks(int iterate){
        for (int i = 0; i < iterate; ++i){
            cout << "Book: ";
            getline(cin, storage[i]);
        }
    }

    const string operator[](const int ref){
        return storage[ref];
    }
    ~Books(){
        delete storage;
    }
};

int main(){
    //local variables 
    int quantity;
    //user display
    cout << "Welcome to Book Storage Viewer" << endl;
    cout << "How many books would you like to insert: ";
    cin >> quantity;
    //instantiante 
    Books bk;
    //other handle
    bk.savebooks(quantity);
    //display books
    cout << "These are the books you've entered" << endl;
    for(int i = 0; i < quantity; ++i){
        cout << bk[i] << endl;
    }
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

also I am not 100% sure if I have coded this correctly and if there are anymore errors please tell me and thanks.

Comment: Could you indicate which line the error occurs on? It's hard for us to tell.

Comment: `storage = new string[book];`? Compile error

Comment: Here @BrianBi I have made it more clear now by displaying the line of error and the column

Comment: yes @gongzhitaao that is where the error occurs

Comment: So, follow the error message and change it to an const integer.

Comment: `operator[]` normally has an overload for a const reference and non-const reference return. In addition, your destructor uses `delete` improperly, you don't follow the Rule of Three (let alone Rule of Zero), your first `getline` call will be "skipped", and you don't check that your input succeeded.

Comment: delete storage will cause segment fault,should be delete [] storage

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This statement

```
    storage = new string[book];
```

is invalid. The subscript value shall have integral or unscopped enueration type.

It seems your class definition has a typo and instead of

```
string book;
```

there should be for example

```
int book;
```

I think you meant the following

```
private:
    string* storage;
    int quantity;
public:
    Books( int quantity) : quantity( quantity ) {
        storage = new string[this->quantity];
    }
    void savebooks(){
        for (int i = 0; i < quantity; ++i){
            cout << "Book: ";
            getline(cin, storage[i]);
        }
    }
//...
```

And in main there should be

```
int quantity;
//user display
cout << "Welcome to Book Storage Viewer" << endl;
cout << "How many books would you like to insert: ";
cin >> quantity;
//instantiante 
Books bk();
bk.savebooks();
```

Comment: But wouldn't that mess up mt entire application if I declare book int

Comment: @user3264250 Data member book is not used in your original code instead of using it incorrectly as a subscript value.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow: and then take it a step further by replacing `string* storage` with `vector<string>` and get rid of `int quantity` altogether.

Answer (score 1):

My suggestions:

1. There is nothing in `Books` to indicate how many books there are. Perhaps you want to pass the number of books in the constructor of `Books'.

   `Books(int numBooks) {
      storage = new string[numBooks];
   }`
2. If you want to store the number of books in `Books`, add member. There is no use for the member `books`. Perhaps you intended to use `books` to store the number of books. If you decide to do that, change `string books;` to `int books;` and make sure you initialize `books` in the constructor.

   `Books(int numBooks) : books(numBooks) {
      storage = new string[numBooks];
   }`
3. If you decide to store the number of books as a member of `Books`, there is no need to pass `quantity` to `savebooks()`. `savebooks()` can be implemented as:

   `void savebooks(){
       for (int i = 0; i < books; ++i){
           cout << "Book: ";
           getline(cin, storage[i]);
       }
   }`

Answer (score 1):

it seems no one metions the segment fault at the end of the program
which due to `delete storage` but it should be `delete [] storage`

I tried to compile the code, and this one is ok when the books is less then 100.

```
   #include <iostream>
    #include <string>
    using namespace std;

    class Books{
    private:
        string* storage;
        string book;
    public:
        Books(){
            storage = new string[100];
        }
        void savebooks(int iterate){
            for (int i = 0; i < iterate; ++i){
                cout << "Book: ";
                getline(cin, storage[i]);
            }
        }

        const string& operator[](const int ref){
            return storage[ref];
        }
        ~Books(){
            delete [] storage;
        }
    };

    int main(){
        //local variables 
        int quantity;
        //user display
        cout << "Welcome to Book Storage Viewer" << endl;
        cout << "How many books would you like to insert: ";
        cin >> quantity;
        //instantiante 
        Books bk;
        //other handle
        bk.savebooks(quantity);
        //display books
        cout << "These are the books you've entered" << endl;
        for(int i = 0; i < quantity; ++i){
            cout << bk[i] << endl;
        }
        return 0;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

What is this?  Doesn't the compiler indicate where the error is?

```
Books(){
        storage = new string[book];
}
```

Comment: Well it does tell me that the red marking is on book

Comment: Correct, because you are using the `new[]` operator to allocate an array of `string` values, and it expects you to specify a numeric value indicating how many `string` values to allocate (`storage = new string[number of strings]`), but you are giving it a `string` instead of a count, so it fails with the error.